# What is the correct entropy density of the cosmic vacuum?

Tags: thermodynamics, cosmology, entropy, thermal-radiation, event-horizon

Which of the following two arguments is correct?

(1) The total entropy of the cosmic vacuum should be the same as the entropy of the cosmological horizon (with radius $R$). The horizon entropy $S$ is given by the black hole entropy $A/4$ (in Planck units); the total cosmic vacuum entropy is thus proportional to $R^2$.

The temperature of the horizon, and of the vacuum in its interior that is due to the horizon (and not to other effects), is $T = 1/R$ (again in Plank units).

(2) Alternatively, the total entropy $S$ of the cosmic vacuum is the entropy of the black body radiation from the horizon: $S = V \cdot \sigma \cdot T^3 / c$.  Therefore, the total entropy $S$ does not depend on $R$, because $V$ changes as $R^3$, and $T^3$ changes as $1/R^3$.

Which of the two entropy expressions is correct? Or are both wrong? Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us evolve the Universe in both arguments to a de Sitter end-point so the 'horizon' is then the future cosmic event horizon in both cases. **What is then clearly the same** in both arguments is that the entropy is:

\begin{equation}\tag{A}
\ S=S_{Bulk}=S_{dS}\sim \frac{E}{T_{dS}} 
\end{equation}
Also, $T_{dS}\approx 2.4\times10^{-30}K$.

The volume of the space enclosed by the future cosmic event horizon   (radius $l_\Lambda$) is simply:
\begin{equation}\tag{B}
V = \frac{4}{3} \pi{l_\Lambda^3} \sim 1.4 \times 10^{79}~\mathrm{m^3}.
\end{equation}
Or, if you feel this volume relation (B) is only valid in dS space with a horizon-based argument, you can use $V=\pi^2l_\Lambda^3$  in argument (2) below, it doesn't change the outcome.

The entropy density $s$ of the cosmic vacuum is $s=S/V$

**What is not the same:**

In argument (1) $E=E_H=E_{Bulk}$. This is a holographic relation. Also, $k_BS_{dS}=E_{dS}/T_{dS}$

In argument (2) $E=E_B=aT_{dS}^4V$. This a black body [radiation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/109043/whats-the-total-cosmic-microwave-background-energy) relation. Also, $k_BS_{dS}=4E_{B}/3T_{dS}$

****Lets look at (2) first****. If this were right, the *energy density* of the cosmic vacuum could be calculated as $\rho_{\Lambda}=E_B/V=aT_{dS}^4\approx2.5\times10^{-134}\mathrm J/m^3$.

Now, the *energy density* of the bulk vacuum is constant over time, and **from observation** is known to be approx.:
\begin{equation}\tag{3}
\rho_{\Lambda} = \frac{\Lambda c^4}{8 \pi G} \sim 6.3 \times 10^{-10}~\mathrm{J/m^3}.
\end{equation}
The ratio of (3) : $\rho_{\Lambda}$ from argument (2) is $\sim10^{124}$. So, what we have with argument (2) is a version of the cosmological constant problem (CCP). In fact, we could expect this, since the CCP arises from relating the degrees of freedom to a sphere volume rather than a sphere surface area, and this is what argument (2) is really doing, trying to relate vacuum energy density to volume. Also, see [these](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/543047/temperature-of-the-vacuum-energy-density) answers why this approach is a 'no'.

**What about (1)?** This is more likely to be correct, since as per [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/507447/entropy-of-de-sitter-spacetime-and-the-10120-vacuum-discrepency/528657#528657) answer, there is a holographic-inspired approach that solves the CCP.